# How to fix object "x" not found

Tags: r

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9PO1.png)

I have a problem when I want to do the lmtest using whitetest.

Anyone might be able to help to solve the problem

script:

```
library(lmtest)
data = read.csv("D:/polidoor.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
white.test(x,y)
```

result:

> library(lmtest)
> data = read.csv("D:/polidoor.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
> white.test(x,y)
> Error in white.test(x, y) : object 'x' not found

Comment: run `ls()` to check if `x` exists in your global environment

Comment: I don't know R so much but I think you should declare x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `x` (or `y`) which you are inputting to the test function.

`x` needs to be a a "numeric vector, matrix, or time series", and `y` needs to be a numeric vector according to [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-47/topics/white.test).

I'm assuming you want to use your data that you imported. This does not automatically put things in the `x` and `y` variable. You need to select columns using [dataframe notation](https://dzone.com/articles/learn-r-how-extract-rows).

For example, if you want your first column to be input feature column, and the second to be the output, you can use

```
x <- data[, 1]
y <- data[, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with`

```
with(data,
   white.test(x,y)
)
```

Assuming `x` and  `y` are columns of `data`.